# Conflict (409) when creating new file

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

When creating a new realtime model for a given file with two accounts at more or less the same time I get this error:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 409 (Conflict) https://drive.google.com/otservice/save?id=1gCma8cExxFTxwXK5jDddLq1Gug4khzV…access_token=ya29.AHES6ZRuMiexU30oMHKo05lGOlpm4fpDqigaxeF_O9EiBllvFnKcs__H

If I get it right from the docs this should not happen as the initializing of the model will only happen once (?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model initialization will only happen once.  I believe that if you make two requests to create a new model at the same time, one of them will succeed and one will fail.  With the failed one, you should be able to recover by reloading the model, which will give you teh one that was successfully created by the other guy.